# UITableView: Force "release tableview" after refresh is completed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView with a refresh control.

When I pull to refresh, the refresh control ist shown. When the refresh is completed, and the user has not released his finger, so the tableview is still in scrolling/dragging state, I want to force a “release” of the scrolling state. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1.- You can stop refreshControl

```
refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
```

2.-You can remove the refresh control but if you want to use it again, you should add it every time after some work

```
refreshControl.removeFromSuperView()
```

or

```
refreshControl = nil
```